# HTML page not getting updated after adding new content via FileZilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

When I add new content to the HTML page, and upload it via FileZilla, the entire content of the page gets deleted.  [This is the link](http://pppnet.org/resource/speakers_bureau.html) for the page that I am trying to update where I just have to add few speakers. But when I add a new speaker and upload it, the webpage shows no content.  All the previous speakers-related data gets deleted too.

The structure of the JSON file is as follows:

```
{
    "speaker": [
        { 
        "name" : "Steve Clark",
        "pic" : "http://www.pppnet.org/resource/speakers_pictures/steve_clark.jpg",
        "email" : "clarks@vt.edu",
        "phone" : "540-231-2816",
        "city" : "Blacksburg",
        "state" : "VA",
        "employer" : "Virginia Tech",
        "bio" : "<p>Steve Clark is the Assistant Vice President for Gift Planning at Virginia Tech, a position he has held since 2011.  He has been with the university since 1994, previously serving as Associate Director of Planned Giving before becoming the Director of Gift Planning in 1998.  Prior to his career in philanthropic planning, he practiced law with firms in Richmond, VA and Abingdon, VA.  He holds both a BA in government and economics and a JD from the University of Virginia. Steve is a former member of the Virginia Gift Planning Council and a current member of the Partnership for Philanthropic Planning of the Blue Ridge, where he has served as President and Vice President for Programs.</p>",
        "topics" : [
            "Marketing/Cultivation",
            "Administration"
        ],
        "presentations" : [
            "Myths of Planned Giving, and How to Address Them",
            "Planned Giving Steps for Charities of Every Size"
        ]
    },
    {       
        "name" : "Johni Hays",
        "pic" : "http://www.pppnet.org/resource/speakers_pictures/johni_hays.jpg",
        "email" : "johni@ceplan.com",
        "phone" : "515-988-8817",
        "city" : "Johnston",
        "state" : "IA",
        "employer" : "Thompson & Associates",
        "bio" : "<p>Johni Hays is Vice President with Thompson & Associates, a charitable estate planning firm. She's a member of PPP's Leadership Institute since 2011. Johni is the author of the book, Essentials of Annuities and co-author of the book, The Tools and Techniques of Charitable Planning. Johni serves on the Editorial Advisory Board for the books Tax Facts on Investments and Tax Facts on Insurance and Employee Benefits. She serves as a charitable planning author of Steve Leimberg’s electronic newsletter service, LISI, found at www.leimbergservices.com. Johni has been quoted in the Wall Street Journal and has published charitable planning articles in Estate Planning Magazine, Planned Giving Today, Fundraising Success, Life Insurance Selling and the National Underwriter.</p><p>Johni frequently lectures to professional advisors as well as donors on estate and charitable planning, probate, living wills, annuities, life insurance, retirement planning and IRAs, as well as income, estate and gift taxation. Johni has been engaged in the practice of law with an emphasis in charitable and estate planning since 1993.</p><p>She previously served as the Senior Gift Planning Consultant for The Stelter Company and prior to that as the Executive Director of the Greater Des Moines Community Foundation Planned Giving Institute. In addition, Johni practiced estate planning with Myers Krause and Stevens, Chartered law firm in Naples Florida, where she specialized in estate planning. She also worked with the insurance industry helping agents with estate and charitable plans for their clients.</p><p>Johni graduated cum laude with a Juris Doctor degree from Drake University in Des Moines, Iowa, in 1993. She also holds a Bachelor of Science degree in Business Administration from Drake University and graduated magna cum laude in 1988</p><p>Johni is a member of the Partnership for Philanthropic Planning (formerly the National Committee on Planned Giving), the Mid-Iowa Planned Giving Council and the Mid-Iowa Estate and Financial Planners Council (president 2007-2008). Johni has been a member of both the Iowa Bar and the Florida Bar since 1993.</p>",
        "topics" : [
            "Integrated Planning",
            "Ethics",
            "Current Events",
            "Gift Design",
            "Other"
        ],
        "presentations" : [
            "Planning Strategies with Tax-Heavy Assets (IRAs, Savings Bonds, Commercial Annuities)",
            "Ethical Issues in Charitable Gift Planning",
            "Hot Topics in Gift Planning",
            "Charitable Planning Strategies that Really Work",
            "Planning Strategies with Tax-Heavy Assets (IRAs, Savings Bonds, Commercial Annuities)",
            "10 Charitable Planning Mistakes to Avoid",
            "Modern Family Estate Planning:  Unmarried Couples and Same-Sex Couple Considerations",
            "Life Income Interests in the Context of Charitable Estate Planning: CGAs and CRTs",
            "What Gift Planners Need to Know About Commercial Annuities",
            "Moving Beyond Securities to Fund CGAs and into the Fun Stuff (life insurance, real estate, commercial annuities)!",
            "The Seven Commandments of Planned Giving"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried that but it din't work out. It seems like I can delete the existing speakers and that is reflected in the web page but not when I add a new speaker.

Comment: @Nick Dugger any suggestions?

Comment: That json file, does it contain ALL of the previous people? If it doesn't how are you importing it?

Comment: @NicholasYoung yes it does have the previous people.

Comment: var my_url = "http://pppnet.org/resource/speakers.json" I have used this in the html file to fetch the data from the spekars.json file where all the data is present @NicholasYoung

Comment: could you post the js snippet your using to display them?

Comment: @NicholasYoung too long to post it in here. can I send it via mail?

Comment: Just give me the direct link to it.

Comment: @NicholasYoung http://pppnet.org/resource/speakers_bureau.html

Comment: I copied your code and it was giving me an error. Look at this snippet and try this for getting your json. http://pastebin.com/SazrF7MM

Comment: @NicholasYoung have tried the code you suggested. When I uploaded it the page couldn't display any of the speakers. It gave me a blank page.

Comment: Its showing everything for me. Clear your browser cache.

Comment: @NicholasYoung I have pasted the code you have sent me in place of the previous code. I have cleared my cache but it still won't display the speakers.

Comment: That is weird, i'm baffled i have no idea.